# Blower resistor 2x3 connector replacement

Tags: wiring, electronics, connector

I had an issue in a Citroën C4 2008 where the blower would work on settings 1-2-3 but not 4 (max). I took out the resistor and found this on the connector that plugs into the resistor:

[image]

As can be seen, the plastic around one pin is melted. I assume this is the culprit of my issue with blower setting 4. The resistor itself is fine (but maybe I'll get another as the male pin in question is all black).

My question is, what is this type of connector called (as I will need to find a replacement)?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It's more than likely going to be called a "blower motor resistor **connector**" or **harness loom repair** kit or some such like that ... I don't know what you'd call  it in Europe, though. I've found some online available in the UK (on Amazon.co.uk), but not your specific one.